# How to share file from angular code to WhatsApp application?

Tags: android, angular, whatsapp, capacitor

I have create sample project in angular 17.1.0. I have some date in json format in the angular application. Now i want to share this json data to WhatsApp application as a file.
I have gone through multiple article and tried multiple approaches but nothing is working.

Sample of code which i have used. but it is still not sharing json data as file in the WhatsApp.

```
shareFileToWhatsApp(jsonData: any, filename: string) {
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jsonData)], { type: 'application/json' });
    const file = new File([blob], filename);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const whatsappUrl = 'whatsapp://send?text=';
   // window.open(newUrl[1])
   console.log("url is:",whatsappUrl + url)
   window.open(whatsappUrl + url) 
  }
```

NOTE:

- Above code is sharing the URL to WhatsApp application as below:

  *blob:http://localhost:4200/e34929f2-4162-4af3-8802-7e15ce18329c*
- But i don't see file attached to it. i can't even download the file using this link as it is not clickable.

What i really what is, once i share the data as file to WhatsApp, i should be able to see file in the application.

I really need help here, i am trying it for more than week and nothing worked out. Please provide a sample code as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what should whatsapp do with the file once you manage to do so?

Comment: It looks more that you try to share an url. Confusing post.

Comment: You share from localhost? What is your intention?

Comment: We should be able to download that file in WhatsApp.  Link is supposed to be the download link for the file once user click. Angular application is running on localhost.